# In Twitter, is the time used of the Twitter's server or of the computer?

Tags: twitter, time

Is the time used by Twitter when posting tweets via its API that of the Twitter's server or of the computer? Or is there something I need to know about Twitter provided its actually real-time and have some GMT differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter is (as any big company) saving all tweets with UTC time and showing them on frontend with localized time depending on the users time zones. That is the "safest" approach for dealing with time in programming.

For more information about timing issues try to have a look at the fabulous explanation from Jon Skeet in NodaTime (same in Java with JodaTime):

[What's wrong with DateTime anyway?](http://noda-time.blogspot.de/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link.